# SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, sapi

I am making a voice recognition program in C# using the built-in Windows speech API. I had this working and all of a sudden after restarting my pc it stopped working. I'm not sure why, and I did try to add in the following code that over 20 different online sources said to add:

`gram.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");`

(I even tried to replace the `"en-GB"` with `"en-US")

This is my console ouput when I run the code:

[Better resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lR1C.png)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/frRBF.png]

And here is my code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    GrammarBuilder gb = new Choices(new GrammarBuilder[] { "Hello", "Test" });

    gb.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

    SpeechRecognitionEngine engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    engine.LoadGrammar(g);
    engine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    engine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(speechRecognized);

    ss.Speak("Enabled!");
}

public static void speechRecognized(object ob, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Result.Text;
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you...

Comment: I was stuck on the same issue and was trying to trouble shoot regarding the message - SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection. However, I realized this is an information message. My sound recognition started to work after I connected a headset with a mic, and went to Control Panel->Speech Recognition and was able to configure speech recognition and got message that the computer was able to hear my voice (although not very clearly).

Comment: @DeepakGarud I think I found the solution. After you register the event handler for the recognition engine, you have to call the method Console.WriteLine();

Comment: @Tyler if you found a solution, it would be nice to share it. Others might have encountered this issue :)